# Not authorized to access type creation GRAPHQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am having trouble with

```
"message": "Not Authorized to access createMerchant on type Merchant"
```

I'm executing this on the AWS AppSync Request tab.

I'm able to list (this one too), create other types but just not this one.

```
input CreateMerchantInput {
    id: ID
    pass: AWSURL
    validated: Boolean!
    _version: Int
}
```

```
type MerchantType @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools {
    id: ID!
    role: String!
    merchantSpotMerchantTypes(
        filter: ModelMerchantSpotMerchantTypeFilterInput,
        sortDirection: ModelSortDirection,
        limit: Int,
        nextToken: String
    ): ModelMerchantSpotMerchantTypeConnection
    createdAt: AWSDateTime!
    updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
    _version: Int!
    _deleted: Boolean
    _lastChangedAt: AWSTimestamp!
}
```

Not sure how to fix this. Rights seem ok to me and I don't know where to look else.

Answer (score 4):

The solution *might* depend on how you're authenticating the call - are you using Cognito? IAM?

"Rights seem ok" ... well, they might seem ok to you but still not be correct :) If it's IAM then you should probably post your policy.

But you don't seem to have any explicit `@auth` directives, so -- in the absence of other info -- I'm going to guess that you're perhaps using Cognito and that you might have some [custom VTL resolvers](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/custom-business-logic/#vtl-resolver) in your amplify project that are affecting `createMerchant` (perhaps accidentally). But it is hard to say for certain without more detail on your project.